# Burrowing with weapons

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons, movement

Given the Trox multiple upper limbs and and burrow trait, does he need to sheathe/put down his weapon before burrowing, or can he burrow all the same?

Comment: I made some small formatting edits. You don't need to include your game system in the title because it's in the tags section. You don't need to preface your question with an introduction; we're here to ask and answer questions, we know that's what this site does. Welcome to the Stack! Make sure to take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour)- it only takes a couple minutes and gives information about how we do things and why it's that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Pathfinder makes no reference to hands needed to Burrow. Even creatures other than a Trox can typically Burrow (if they have the ability) while armed.

Barring GM's making their own decision on the matter, we have very limited rules relating to Burrowing.

First, from d20SRD.org (because Pathfinder did not copy the OGL passage, nor make their own):

> A creature with a burrow speed can tunnel through dirt, but not through rock unless the descriptive text says otherwise. Creatures cannot charge or run while burrowing. Most burrowing creatures do not leave behind tunnels other creatures can use (either because the material they tunnel through fills in behind them or because they do not actually dislocate any material when burrowing); see the individual creature descriptions for details.

Or, the Trox's own Burrow trait:

> Trox have the burrow movement ability. (3 RP) They gain a burrow speed of 20 feet.

Which is pretty straightforward.

However; the best evidence is probably the [Burrow](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/burrow/) spell. It is Paizo material and contains the following notes:

> Using burrow requires only as much concentration as walking, so the subject can attack or cast spells normally. The burrowing creature cannot charge or run.

This seems to imply that you have no problem holding whatever spell components, weapons, or other objects you need while making use of the ability. Spells are sometimes exceptions to the rules, but when there are no rules to be excepted they can be guidelines for how to run things.

---

As a GM, I would question other creatures Burrowing while armed, but the Troxs' extra limbs would be plenty of justification to allow it.

Comment: Id argue that some creatures may use their limbs and/or claws to burrow. But that's not the case to *all* creatures.

Comment: Thank you very much for the exhaustive answer.

Comment: @ShadowKras Yeah that's why I put in the GM note at the bottom. In the end, it has to be a table decision (although I see no issue with Trox as OP asked)